# Android List item click horizontal menu

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The attached UI is the calllog. What i am interested is that how the horizontal menu is implemented. When click on one list item, it appeared in one line under the list item.

In the earlier android, one click on list item, we can use Context menu popup menu to show the available action to do.

I am curious that it is using expandable list view concept? 
I want to design like that when click on list item to show like this, but my layout would not be the same as this one. I want to put custom layout depending on the list item type. It may include button, textview, other widgets and the layout height will not be the list item height.

Can someone give some suggestion? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Add a hidden view to your item layout, and in your itemClickListener toggle its visibility

Comment: Then every list item needs a another invisible list item. Dynamic loading data will be difficult.

Comment: Alexandre BOURETZ i found the same way as you suggested https://gist.github.com/luksprog/3722950#file-adapters_adapterwithmenu-xml-L19
Thanks a lot.